# How to get the index of match string in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get the index of the exact search string, I have built a function that returns the index the match strings where I need to  get the index only with the exact match

here is my function

```
getIndicesOf = (searchStr, str) => {
              var searchStrLen = searchStr.length;
              if (searchStrLen === 0) {
                return [];
              }
              var startIndex = 0,
                index,
                indices = [];
              while ((index = str.indexOf(searchStr, startIndex)) > -1) {
                indices.push(index);
                startIndex = index + searchStrLen;
              }
               console.log("detercting " , indices );
            return indices;
};
console.log(getIndicesOf("go" , "go, I am going ")); //  [0, 9]
```

here I go the index of go and going , How can  get  the index only  of the exact match string?

Comment: What output were you expecting instead?

Comment: The first occurance of go also contains a semicolon. "go," so it is not an exact match. right ?

Comment: the first one is an exact match but the second one is not , So I do not want to get the index of it

Comment: Your `str` is `"go, I am going "` which contains no semicolons? Did you want to forbid commas after the "o"? Or did you want to forbid more words after the "o"? (with those conditions, nothing will be matched given your input)

Answer (score 2):

The first occurrence of go also contains a comma. So it is not an exact match.

If you still want to get all the indices of ***go*** and ***go,*** in the words array, you can use the following script.

```
var x = "go, I am going go";
arr = x.split(" ");
arr.map((e, i) => (e === "go" || e === "go,") ? i : '').filter(String)
```

If you need to find the index in the string you can use the below approach

```
var x = "go, I am going go";
arr = x.split(" "); var index = 0;
arr.map((e, i) => {
     var occur = (e === "go" || e === "go,") ? index : '';
     index+=e.length+1;
     return occur}).filter(String)
```

Comment: I prefer this approach I am going to try it in my code can't tell if it will work because I am using draf.js with my react.js application thank you so much dude

Answer (score 1):

replace your while loop with this code,

```
 while ((index = str.indexOf(searchStr, startIndex)) > -1) {
        if(str.substring(startIndex,searchStrLen) == searchStr)
        {
                indices.push(index);
                startIndex = index + searchStrLen;
        }
}
```